# Is it acceptable to select a random child node when using a Decision Tree (trained via ID3) to predict if an unknown attribute value is encountered

Tags: algorithms, decision-trees

I am writing a decision tree trained with the ID3 algorithm from scratch. I wanted to be able to train on and classify continuous data, so I implemented k-means clustering and reduced the range of values of any input training or predicting data.

However, I ran into the problem where an attribute value that was not encountered during training, in a deep node somewhere in the tree, but that exists further up was encountered. All data points with this specific attribute value probably ended up on a different branch of the tree.

So to 'solve' this, whenever an unknown attribute value is encountered for a node, I sent it down a random existing branch.

I get 95.45% accuracy using randomly split 85%-15% training-test data with iris.

Is this an acceptable approach to take or have I gotten something wrong here?

Here's the code: https://github.com/jamalmoir/ml_components/blob/master/ml_components/models/decision_tree.py

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do your leaf nodes return a probability distribution rather than a single class value *e.g.*, the majority class of training instances that arrived at the node? If so, a better approach would be to send the test instance down every child path and average the probability distributions that are returned by the leaves.

Your good score of 95.45% on iris data suggests to me that it's not a very important detail in this example. Try some more challenging datasets and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: My leaf nodes just return a class label... Maybe I could look into probability distributions then. Thanks for the suggestion!

I'll take a look at more challenging datasets. Thanks

Comment: It's a good idea to be returning distributions from your decision trees, because if you want to make an ensemble of decision trees, averaging the distributions will give you a more accurate classification than simply voting.

Comment: I see, that's a good point. Thank you. I will definitely work on building probability distributions into my decision trees.